# Php 5.3 magick quotes gpc

Tags: php, mysql, php-5.3

I have a problem, an old program with mysql querys doesn't works in new php 5.3 with magick_quotes_gpc disabled, when a variable of query have single quote, ex:

```
$text=$_GET['text'] --> "This is a text doesn'**strong text**t works"
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET '{$text}'");
```

Only works if I make previously this:

```
$text=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['text']);
```

But I can't modify the program, and the program is to big and have a lot of querys, which I can i do?

Comment: magick_quotes_gpc is only deprecated in 5.3, not removed.  Enable it, either in php.ini or your apache configuration, e.g. `php_value magic_quotes_gpc 1`.  This is, of course, the Wrong Way to do things, but you've made it pretty clear that The Right Way is not practical in your situation.

Comment: `$_POST = array_map("mysql_real_escape_string", $_POST);` is a suitable replacement for magic quotes.

Comment: magick_quotes_gpc is not removed from 5.3 but will be removed from 5.4 so you'd better find another solution. Mario's idea works with a few caveats: 1) you can only use mysql_real_escape_string after making a connection to a database and 2) it will only work if your $_POST contains only strings. It's possible for $_POST (or $_GET for that matter) to contain arrays.

Comment: When yo say "if you $_POST contains only strings" you trust the value can't be numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I can't modify the program, and the program is to big and have a lot of querys, which I can i do?

If you can't modify the program, then you should enable [`magic_quotes_gpc`](http://php.net/manual/security.magicquotes.php) - the feature itself is still available in php 5.3 - only deprecated.

Upgrading to php 5.4 and running the application however would be a security issue. So after you've now been warned about deprecation, consider how you want to keep the maintenance for the application in question in the future.

Comment: Finaly I modify the program, replace all $_GET variables for mysql_escape_string($_GET['variable']) iniside the query. I have class to work with database and I add new method like pdo->quote() to do this

Answer (score -2):

Don't enable `magic_quotes_gpc`.

> This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.

You can run a search and replace on your code and replace all occurences of `$_GET[]` with `mysql_real_escape_string($_GET[]);`