# If something is deprecated in php 5.3.10, can it be made to work anyway?

Tags: php

I have a site running a php app that I wrote. The site was just upgraded and now uses php 5.3.10. The first thing that I noticed is that `$HTTP_POST_VARS` no longer works. That led me to the fact that this is apparently deprecated.

**I need to keep this app running**. Is there any way to simply tell php to ignore the deprecation errors and warnings and to just keep using deprecated variables and functions?

I've search but can't find an answer - maybe because it's "No"?

Comment: Why not updating the code, appearently you updated PHP, so get rid of this old stuff.

Comment: Yep, it's much better to work with the PHP development process than against it. Recommended practice is to check the change logs for the version you're moving to and determine if your site will be compatible; if not then decide whether you'll be best sticking with your current version and porting functionality back, or upgrading and updating your code to match. Things are deprecated for a reason.

Answer (score 3):

The [`$HTTP_POST_VARS`](http://php.net/HTTP_POST_VARS) does still work in PHP 5.3.10, it's only deprecated.

Deprecation errors are ignored by default, your program does just work. It only warns you that you're using a feature that might not be available in the future any longer.

Please compare this with the similar question **[Php 5.3 magick quotes gpc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10628032/367456)** that is about deprectation with PHP 5.3 as well.

The new name of it is [`$_POST`](http://php.net/_POST) which is exactly the same. So you only need to put your code under version control, replace the usage (refactor: rename variable) and you should be very fine for the future as well.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's a bad idea you could append this line in a file that gets included in every page(something like config.php in most scripts) and $HTTP_POST_VARS should work

```
$HTTP_POST_VARS = $_POST;
```

The fact that this is a bad idea and that you should update your script to replace deprecated variables needs to be stressed.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace it with `$_POST`. They contain the same data, the difference is `$_POST` is superglobal.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem! But it's as simple as changing `$HTTP_POST_VARS` to `$_POST` - This worked for me and I don't see why it won't for you.